# How to make mtp devices resemble hard drive?

Tags: android

Is there any way to make MTP devices work as a real filesystem ? such as to perform copy/paste or move operations like it was an actual hard drive?

Comment: You don't. The only way to do it would be to rewrite the firmware of the device in question so that it unloaded the operating system and then rebooted in a "disk only" mode.

Comment: The MTP protocol is too simple to work as a real file system.

Comment: Dup marking is incorrect. Pist shluld be reopened.

Comment: It is entirely possible to make mtp work like a filesystem and allow copy-pasting.   I believe its built into some Linux GUI's - eg Ubuntu.  Even before this  or if needed at the command line there are FUSE modules to do it.  Of-course, mtp does not allow block device level access - but thats not really what the OP asked.

Comment: MTP is intended to allow the phone to retain control and access to the filesystem while giving access over USB. The "old style" that was accessed via USB mass storage worked by unmounting the "storage" partition in android and instead share it over USB. The problem there was that it absolutely mandated having separate storage and OS partitions under Android. Those separated partitions meant that applications and the operating system ended up with a fixed space. You end up with the situation where you have plenty of "storage" free but unable to install applications.

Comment: @davidgo the dupe is "How to make a smartphone (MTP Device) work as USB storage (real filesystem)" and that is basically the first sentence in this question. The answer is that you no longer *can* make modern Android devices function that way. Other than that under Windows MTP is essentially copy/paste and built into Explorer, and otherwise depends on what OP uses. This question is either a duplicate or way too vague.

Comment: @Mokubai ...or both